# Calling and using variables in a Chrome Extention

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, iframe

I'm currently working on an extension for chrome, the main aim for the extension is to display listener stats for the stations hosted on my servers.
I need to take a variable (In this case the variable is the mount point and then put it on the end of a URL in an Iframe.
Here is the Iframe.

```
 <iframe id="stats" src="http://free.myfreeradiostream.com:8009/status3.xsl?mount=/mount23.mp3" frameBorder="0" width="500px"  scrolling="no">
```

I need to take the users input through a form and then insert it at the end of the mount part,
For example if I was using mount30.mp3, I would type it in a form, press submit and the extension would replace mount23.mp3 with my mount.
I would use PHP to do this but since It's Chrome I can't, I have looked at JS but I can't figure it out.
Any help will be great, thanks!

Comment: Please add more details to your question: do you need full JS code (for getting the value out of the input box), to change the iframe or just sending the variable trough a content script towards the extension.

Comment: I need the JS code to get the value as you said, I'm not too sure how to use variables in JS, It basically needs to take the user input, eg Mount1.mp3 and then put it on the end of the Src for the Iframe and then load it.